# GetProfile webservice not working

Tags: infopath, web-services

I was using a data connection called GetProfile to get some users data. From yesterday I am getting a below error
“The settings for one or more data connections in your form are defined in a data connection library on a microsoft sharepoint server to retrieve this settings the form must be published to the server that contains the data connection library and form must be opened from the published location”

The GetProfile webservice is not displaying any user information on the form. what is the solution for this ? please suggest

Comment: Does your site (still) have a Data connection Library?

Comment: yes I created a data connection library and uploaded it with GetProfile webservice